# Make WPF TextBox begin at a certain location in the box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I can't seem to find the answer online when I search around, I don't know if this is because there is an easier way that I don't know about.

I want my text box text to begin after the line on the picture below:

[image]

Is there something that I can set in the XAML or in he C# code.

Also, if there is a solution, the data that the user enters it getting stored in a database so I don't want there to be space before there data if you get me.

Any idea's please let me know, Thanks.

```
<Label Content="Firstname:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFACACAC" FontSize="13"/>

<TextBox x:Name="txtFirstname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="59,166,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433" PreviewTextInput="TextOnlyValidation" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" />

<GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="190,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1" Background="#FFACACAC"/>
```

Comment: You can set an appropriate `Padding`.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah, sure look again in few seconds.

Comment: Why are your margin settings so big?  When I lay these out, I use a Grid control & usually set the margins to 5, which puts a 5 pixel border around everything.  The `Grid` is there to space & size the controls in it.  Let the controls stretch to fill the `Grid` cell & use the `ColumnDefinition` object's `Width` property to control the width of the control.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I just tried adding Padding = "15" but then it wont even allow me to click to Textbox, so I lowered it but it doesn't move.

Comment: @TonyVitabile I am going to wrap a ViewBox around my controls to control this. I might start the grid separation soon.

Comment: @Ben the `ViewBox` control's job is to scale its contents so they always look the same no matter what the screen's resolution is.  It is not to control layout.  I'm afraid that isn't going to work either.

Comment: I meant just a left padding: `Padding="30,0,0,0"`

Comment: Why do you want a Label over a TextBox?  Why would you hide part of a TextBox?  That is data entry space that is hidden.

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of control. A TextBox is something that allows text to be entered - that is it. It isn't something that also displays a label. You should either (a) create your own custom control which is a textbox-with-label-inside control, or (b) rethink your use of UI components and use them how they are intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned a couple of problems.

(1) Want text to appear after that line
Solution is to set padding, so that there is a large dead-space on the left of the textbox. How much? However wide your label is, or whatever it takes to get to the line.
Use something like `Padding="15,0,0,0"` to just set the left padding.

(2) Adding padding won't let you click in TextBox
Click where? Over the label, or to the right of the line? You can set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the label to ensure it doesn't get in the way of your clicking.

But finally, this is not a great design. You've got absolute positions for Margin whereas you want to try and create a layout that flows and adapts to the space given. A Grid will help with this. You're also trying to overlay two UI elements, and then work around problems introduced by doing this. This is a clear sign you're doing things wrong! The best solution, if a control doesn't do what you want, is to create your own control derived from those that are closest to what you want. You would be better off creating your own TextBox-with-inbuilt-label component and using that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to have to look in creating my own control from a textbox and see what I can do, this is the best answer so far though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new style for your TextBox, and change the layout inside it :

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="-2,0,0,0"/>
                                <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label Content="Firstname :" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="9.333"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your text here" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158.333" Margin="124.594,107.556,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a grid with 2 columns around the label and textbox.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Firstname:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFACACAC" FontSize="13"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtFirstname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="59,166,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433" PreviewTextInput="TextOnlyValidation" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the correct amount of padding:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Firstname" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Padding="10,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: When I use this it wont have the label over the textbox as you separating them using grids?

Comment: You want the label over the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid spaces in your value you can use :

```
string firstname = txtFirstname.text.Trim()
```

Info : [Trim](http://www.dotnetperls.com/trim)